# How to clean up flatpak files in ~/.local/share/flatpak/repo/objects/?

Tags: debian, flatpak, disk-cleanup

`flatpak list` shows me that I only have one app and `Freedesktop.org Software Development Kit` (probably dependency for that app; ca 900MB) installed with flatpak and `flatpak uninstall --unused` returns `Nothing unused to uninstall` but the size of `/home/username/.local/share/flatpak/repo/objects/` is much larger than I would suspect (over 1.5 GB; there are many folders with two-char names with many .files with UID names).

Can this folder be cleaned up somehow without uninstalling that app or flatpak? I'm using Debian11/KDE.

[Related question.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1285690/what-is-home-me-local-share-flatpak-and-how-to-remove-it)

Answer (score 0):

The runtimes, apps etc. for the current user are stored inside the directory you mention. If you don't want the application, you should *not* remove the folder rather uninstall the application using the regular `flatpak uninstall` command.

If you prefer to use the system-wide installations, you could just pass `flatpak --user uninstall --all` and it will remove all the local (i.e. current user) applications. This will save you the space.

Comment: While useful I explicitly asked about ways `without uninstalling that app or flatpak?` and uninstalling usually never refers to deleting folders.

Comment: @mYnDstrEAm "and uninstalling usually never refers to deleting folders" <- to be honest, this site sort of requires people to give an ELI5 explanation due to the fact that one might be talking to a user who's new to Linux or similar. I get that you're a power-user, but not everyone is. Anyway, you could try to see if `flatpak repair --user` might sort your issue. If that doesn't work, then the files inside shouldn't be touched, unless you don't care if you break something.

Comment: That command is useful but it didn't solve the problem. Maybe the app is supposed to require this much disk space, I'll try to find out. Agree that things here should be user-friendly, it was explicitly not the topic of the question and people looking for uninstalling probably search for how to uninstall flatpak apps, not for what I asked about, but maybe I should have added it...would be best suited as a comment, not an answer.

Comment: I just uninstalled it. The app took up half the size and the SDK (edited the question) the other half. I don't know how to check if it's supposed to be this large. The uninstall command is already in the question so even newcomers who intend to uninstall would learn about that.